# View all ACF Flexible content in posts on archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to display ACF Flexible content in all single posts on an archive page. Currently the following code on my Archive page displays only the last posts Flexible content. I would like to display all posts using flexible content on an archive page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
if( have_rows('fabric') ):
while ( have_rows('fabric') ) : the_row(); 
?>


<div class="sales-wrap-info-single">
<?php if( get_sub_field('image') ): ?>
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" />
<? endif ?>
</div>


<?php 
endwhile;
else :
// no rows found
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Add your full code including your archive page loop to display the posts.